# backup & restore timeshift

Tags: backup, timeshift

i was using 22.04 for a month then i read an article about timeshift and started using it. but yesterday i first upgraded to 23.04 and then after few hours again upgraded to 23.10 because i wanted to try genome extension " astra monitor" but after few minutes it felt like it was choking the new 23.10 so after removing it accidentally i used timeshift and used an image i think it was the 22.04 or 23.04 i m not sure but during restoration it went black screen i tried every thing and every available method but said su: not found .

then i thought why not try repairing using bootable pendrive but repairing option was not there tried the terminal nothing ther also , so i tried a fresh install 23.10

now everything is fine except my data is lost
if you find this funny enough then
please suggest a similar software or a method so i dont do this kind of mistake again

Comment: Ubuntu 23.04 support ends January 25, 2024  Generally better to stay with LTS versions unless you have very new hardware that needs the latest. And LTS with Enablement stack hwe also updates to newer kernel. I prefer rsync of my data & /home  (multple places & times) and total reinstall if needed. https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2482329&page=2&p=14124545#post14124545 & https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BackupYourSystem & 
https://help.ubuntu.com/community/CategoryBackupRecovery

Comment: Not funny at all. Next time: Real, not-complicated backups are a great friend on a bad day.